# Unable to find key for specefic value in swift Dictionary

Tags: swift, string, xcode, nsdictionary, urlsession

i tried to get tempFileName from URLSession error and decode resumeData to a dictionary with below code

```
let resumeDictionary = try! PropertyListSerialization.propertyList(from: data, options: [], format: nil) as? [AnyHashable : Any]
```

resumeDictionary contains below string

> > [AnyHashable("$archiver"): NSKeyedArchiver, AnyHashable("$objects"): <__NSCFArray 0x2819140d0>( $null, {
> > "$class" = "<CFKeyedArchiverUID 0x282221520 [0x1dc4981b8]>{value = 19}";
> > "NS.keys" =     (
> > "<CFKeyedArchiverUID 0x282221320 [0x1dc4981b8]>{value = 2}",
> > "<CFKeyedArchiverUID 0x282221340 [0x1dc4981b8]>{value = 3}",
> > "<CFKeyedArchiverUID 0x282221360 [0x1dc4981b8]>{value = 4}",
> > "<CFKeyedArchiverUID 0x282221380 [0x1dc4981b8]>{value = 5}",
> > "<CFKeyedArchiverUID 0x2822213a0 [0x1dc4981b8]>{value = 6}",
> > "<CFKeyedArchiverUID 0x2822213c0 [0x1dc4981b8]>{value = 7}",
> > "<CFKeyedArchiverUID 0x2822213e0 [0x1dc4981b8]>{value = 8}",
> > "<CFKeyedArchiverUID 0x282221400 [0x1dc4981b8]>{value = 9}"
> > );
> > "NS.objects" =     (
> > "<CFKeyedArchiverUID 0x282221420 [0x1dc4981b8]>{value = 10}",
> > "<CFKeyedArchiverUID 0x282221440 [0x1dc4981b8]>{value = 12}",
> > "<CFKeyedArchiverUID 0x282221460 [0x1dc4981b8]>{value = 13}",
> > "<CFKeyedArchiverUID 0x282221480 [0x1dc4981b8]>{value = 14}",
> > "<CFKeyedArchiverUID 0x2822214a0 [0x1dc4981b8]>{value = 15}",
> > "<CFKeyedArchiverUID 0x2822214c0 [0x1dc4981b8]>{value = 16}",
> > "<CFKeyedArchiverUID 0x2822214e0 [0x1dc4981b8]>{value = 17}",
> > "<CFKeyedArchiverUID 0x282221500 [0x1dc4981b8]>{value = 18}"
> > ); }, NSURLSessionResumeCurrentRequest, NSURLSessionResumeOriginalRequest, NSURLSessionDownloadURL,
> > NSURLSessionResumeInfoTempFileName, NSURLSessionResumeBytesReceived,
> > NSURLSessionResumeEntityTag, NSURLSessionResumeInfoVersion,
> > NSURLSessionResumeServerDownloadDate, {
> > "$class" = "<CFKeyedArchiverUID 0x282221540 [0x1dc4981b8]>{value = 11}";
> > "NS.data" = {length = 2427, bytes = 0x62706c69 73743030 d4010203 04050607 ... 00000000 0000083b }; }, {
> > "$classes" =     (
> > NSMutableData,
> > NSData,
> > NSObject
> > );
> > "$classname" = NSMutableData; }, {
> > "$class" = "<CFKeyedArchiverUID 0x282221540 [0x1dc4981b8]>{value = 11}";
> > "NS.data" = {length = 1666, bytes = 0x62706c69 73743030 d4010203 04050607 ... 00000000 00000594 }; },
> > https://file-examples-com.github.io/uploads/2017/04/file_example_MP4_1280_10MG.mp4,
> > CFNetworkDownload_BVLTmU.tmp, 871422, "5f074cdf-962771", 5, Thu, 09
> > Jul 2020 16:59:11 GMT, {
> > "$classes" =     (
> > NSMutableDictionary,
> > NSDictionary,
> > NSObject
> > );
> > "$classname" = NSMutableDictionary; } ) , AnyHashable("$top"): {
> > NSKeyedArchiveRootObjectKey = "<CFKeyedArchiverUID 0x2822212c0 [0x1dc4981b8]>{value = 1}"; }, AnyHashable("$version"): 100000]

the value i want in this string is "CFNetworkDownload_BVLTmU.tmp" which i dont know how to get it in code i dont see any key value for it can somebody help me
?

Answer (score 0):

If I get it right you're trying to lookup a specific element by its value into a `Dictionary<AnyHasable, Any>`… Then you have to rely on `first(where:)` and in the closure do type casting of the element's value to the type of the value (which has to conform to `Equatable`) you're looking for and then check for equality against it.

Something as in:

```
if let element = dictionary.first(where: { ($0 as? Int) == valueToFind }) {
   // do what you have to do with such element…
}
```